# Symfony2 PDF is of invalid format when downloading it on Android

Tags: php, android, pdf, symfony

I'm using this code to prompt for a file download on Symfony 2.7. It's working on Windows/Mac/iPhone, but not on Android:

```
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('File not found.');
        }

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);
        $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
        $response->setContentDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            $name,
            iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name)
        );
```

When *tapping* the link, the download starts but then the error appears: **Filename.pdf is of invalid format**. If I **press** the link and select "Save Link", then the PDF si downloaded correctly and I can open it.

Does anyone know how to fix the download on Android? (tested using version 5).

Thank you

Comment: What Bundle are you using for file handling in Symfony? Also, you mention version 5, is that and Android version? Where's the rest of your controller code, or are you **absolutely** sure the problem is in the code you have posted?

Comment: No Bundle. BinaryFileResponse is part of Symfony's core. And yes, Android version 5. I'm **absolutely** sure the problem is in the code I posted. I could post the rest of the controller but it's not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code it's not the problem. I changed the file extension to **uppercase** and now it's working on Android: filename.pdf -> filename.**PDF** Stupid, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    'filename.pdf'
);
```

Don't know what your PDF would be referred to. Essentially adding the 'Content-Type' headers of PDF to see if that makes a difference. I'm not certain if this will work.

Edit #2
I saw this link:
http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

So try this header change:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'octet-stream');
$response->setContentDisposition(
  ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
  'filename.pdf'
);
```

Try it, and see if that changes the result.

Comment: I tried it and it's not working: same *is of invalid format* message.

Comment: Made a second edit to my post - can you try that please?

Comment: Still not working. But reading that article I solved it. It seems link the code it's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, thanks for your answer. I searched and found this:

http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

Looks like there is a problem with older versions of Android. Maybe in your code you can check for that, and create the proper CASE for the file based on the browser.